# SSRS: How to add data table on x-axis?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, linechart

**SSRS** : I am trying to create **a graph which can have a data-Table on X-axis**. how can i achieve this below graph? any idea ?

image is showing the data. i want Values on Y-Axis and X-axis should contain multiple rows.

[image: image is showing the data. i want Values on Y-Axis and X-axis should contain multiple rows.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't put a table in axis. But there is walk-around. create a chart with dates on x axis, then a table (matrix) immediately below the chart, you have to experiment with the width of the column group (where dates sit) and location of the table so that the dates column in the table align with the dates in the x axis. And then you can hide the dates in the table, so that the report looks like the picture shown. The chart and the table cab be generated from the same of different data sets (depending on your business rule).

Comment: Hi thotwielder i have already tried the above option that you have suggested and it gives the correct solution but only when number of dates are fix on x-axis. when my data is varying and number of dates on x-axis is increased, the alignment of the table will get disturbed. so i found out a solution in which i can vary the width of the column dynamically, but unfortunately, i couldn't find any solution that gave me dynamic width for column.

Comment: i could achieve it by a small trick: just make x-Axis category type. and in the label expression, put newlines when needed. it gives a tabel feel in x-axis.

Comment: that's interesting approach!

Comment: Thanks @thotwielder